# Mean, Median and Mode

Tags: java, java-7, mean, median, mode

Hi I'm having problem with my codes on the Modal value. Here is my code:

```
public class basicStatistics {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    int[] arrCount = new int[n];
    int maxCount = 0;
    double median = 0.0, mean = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        mean = mean + arr[i];
    }
    mean = mean/n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                arrCount[i]++;
            }
        if(maxCount < arrCount[i])
            maxCount = i;
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    if(n%2 == 0) {
        median = arr[n/2] + arr[n/2-1]; 
        median = median/2;
    } else {
        median = arr[n/2];
    }
    System.out.printf("%.1f\n", mean);
    System.out.printf("%.1f\n", median);
    System.out.println(arr[maxCount]);
 }
}
```

The issue is I can't get the Modal value right when the input is this: http://pastebin.com/HCqTrimY I used pastebin as it inputs 2500 numbers. My code outputs the array value 259 instead of 2184 for Mode however if the input is n = 10 and the numbers = 64630 11735 14216 99233 14470 4978 73429 38120 51135 67060 I get the mode value correct or for other scenario.

I also wanted to transform the code to a more efficient one utilizing the Java8 structure. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: do you really want to test `if(arr[i] == arr[j])` if `i==j` ?

Comment: hmm.. I was thinking about that i removed it on my second revision. How would I eliminate it? what I before is I added a if(i != j) { ... } above the if(arr[i]==arr[j]) { ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Java 8, you can make that code a lot shorter. First, the `mean`: Here you can create a `stream` from your `int`-array `arr` and then just call the `average` method:

```
double mean = IntStream.of(arr).average().getAsDouble();
```

The `median` is pretty much the same as in your code; I just put it on fewer lines by using a ternary expression (`... ? ... : ...`) instead of a multi-line `if/else`:

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
int len = arr.length;
double median = len % 2 == 0 ? (arr[len/2-1] + arr[len/2]) / 2. : arr[len/2];
```

The `mode` is a bit more difficult, last but not least since you seem to need the smallest mode in case there are multiple numbers appearing most often. While your double-`for`-loop approach would work, too, it has quadratic complexity, which could become a problem for larger data sets. Instead, you should use a `Map` to count the different numbers. In Java 8, this can be done very easily using `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.counting`. Then, just determine the `max` of the counts, `filter` the numbers that have that count, and get the `min` of those.

```
Map<Integer, Long> counts = IntStream.of(arr).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
Long max = counts.values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
int mode = counts.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(max))
        .min(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey)).get().getKey();
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I needed to transform it on fewer lines of code, I'm new to the lambda and just starting to learn it. I have an issue with the mode it doesn't return the correct answer if my input = 10 and the numbers are 64630 11735 14216 99233 14470 4978 73429 38120 51135 67060.

Comment: @Cham When I use it on that data I get `4978`. What do you get, and what is supposed to be the "right" mode? (Mathematically, they are _all_ correct.)

Comment: It should be 4978 the smallest, what I get with my code is 11735.

Comment: @Cham As I said, 4978 is what I get with that code. When you say you get 11735 with _your_ code, do you mean the code from _my_ answer, or the code from _yours_?

Comment: The code from mine I haven't transformed it to your code yet. I want to learn what is causing the modal value to be incorrect.

Comment: Hi Sir @tobias_k, I've found out the solution I need to add this if statement if (i != j) before evaluating if (arr[i] == arr[j]) { ... } thank you you have been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I answered my own problem. The answer is to put the array sort above the method to get the maxCount here:

```
    ...
    mean = mean/n;
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                arrCount[i]++;
            }
        if(maxCount < arrCount[i])
            maxCount = i;
        }
    }
    if(n%2 == 0) { ...
```

Now the only question is to transform this to a Java8 structure. EDIT: A new issue arises when I tried the input n = 10; numbers are 64630 11735 14216 99233 14470 4978 73429 38120 51135 67060 it doesn't get the modal value correctly which is supposed to be 4978 it outputs 11735.

EDIT: To fix the new error I had to add this code if(i != j) {... } before evaluating if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {...}.

Comment: Why is the modal value supposed to be 4978? All the values appear equally often (once). If multiple modals exist, should the function return the smallest?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "transform this to a Java8 structure"? It would also be more efficient to use increments like mean += arr[i]; instead of mean = mean + arr[i];

For your problem: Try this one:

```
int maxCount = 0;
final int[] arrCount = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if(i != j && arr[i] == arr[j])
            arrCount[i]++;
    }
    if(maxCount < arrCount[i])
        maxCount = i;
}
```

Comment: I just found your answer and it is the solution to my new problem! Thank you!